# What's the total cost of every TH level combined?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How much gold dose it take to upgrade every town hall level? And the cost of gold for every builder hall level to?

Comment: What's preventing you from getting this information yourself? A quick google search for "clash of clans town hall" will bring you to the wiki page for them which has a table at the bottom of the page showing the totals for each town hall level. At that point its just some quick math to get the total cost of all town halls.

Answer (score 2):

It takes 40,630,000 gold to max out the [Town Hall](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Cumulative_Costs/Home_Village) and 10,233,500 to max out the [Builder Hall](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Cumulative_Costs/Builder_Base).